# SHA1 not consistent with keytool

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, sha1

I am facing a very weird problem with my Google Maps API key on an app that has been working without problems for long.
Now, when I run my app in AS, I get the very famous

**Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled**

with cert_fingerprint package_name D6:C3:E6:F2:xxxx;com.yyy

BUT the problem is that when I do keytool on my keystore, the SHA1 displayed is FE:BF:BF:75:xxx

How comes that AS requests a non-existing fingerprint?
I went as far as adding this key in Developers Console, but that doesnt change anything.
I did Clean and Inavlidate caches, but to avail.

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Studio then just create a [*MapActivity*](https://developer.android.com/training/maps/index.html) using android studio and after creating it go into `google_maps_api.xml` and in there there will be a link given in comments. If you paste it in your browser, it will ask a few details to be filled and after that your API will be generated.

At the time of creating the new application. The `SHA-1` and Package names are already in the link given so you do not need to know them. They will however be in your project in the `resources > Values > google_maps_api.xml` file which is completed when you follow the [instructions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup#release-cert) on creating the project.

Follow this tutorial for creating SHA1 fingerprint for Google Map http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/12/displaying-sha1-certificate-fingerprint.html

To generate SHA-1 fingerprint Certificate, enter the following:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```